# Error al instalar Ubuntu 16.04.6.descktop -i386 en VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, instalacion

Muy buenas a todos. El problema que estoy teniendo, es que a la hora de iniciar Ubuntu 32bits en una maquina virtual con VirtualBox, comienza normal hasta los dos segundos que se me congela en la siguiente imagen. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La maquina con la que estoy creando la maquina virtual es un Window 7 32bits. 
Quisiera saber si alguien tiene idea de por que me sale esta pantalla. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo uso las imagenes que te dejare en el siguiente link:
(en este caso es para arquitectura de 32 bits) y como dato adicional te dejare otra respuesta ;).

[Link Aqui!!](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.4/)

Otra Solucion puede ser:
Run VirtualBox.exe, click Settings, select System in the left pane then go in

Processor tab.

Check Enable PAE/NX.

En caso de que el error continue :

Go to your virtual machine -> Settings -> System
Then change Chipset from PIIX3 to ICH9 and enable "Enable IO APIC"

Answer (score 0):

Para sistemas de 64Bits ir a VBox seleccionar la maquina virtual Configuracion / Sistema /Procesador /cargar mas de un CPU

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).